# A Binomial Coefficient Sum: $\sum_{m = 0}^{n} (-1)^{n-m} \binom{n}{m} \binom{m-1}{l}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

In my work on $f$-vectors in polytopes, I ran across an interesting sum which has resisted all attempts of algebraic simplification. Does the following binomial coefficient sum simplify?
\begin{align}
\sum_{m = 0}^{n} (-1)^{n-m} \binom{n}{m} \binom{m-1}{l} \qquad l \geq 0
\end{align}
*Update:* After some numerical work, I believe a binomial sum orthogonality identity is at work here because I see only $\pm 1$ and zeros. Any help would certainly be appreciated.

I take $\binom{-1}{l} = (-1)^{l}$, $\binom{m-1}{l} = 0$ for $0 < m < l$ and the standard definition otherwise.

Thanks!

Comment: Does your summation begin from $m = l+1$?

Comment: Then I assume you need to interpret $\binom{n}{r} = 0$ when $n < r$?

Comment: Perhaps you could mention how it arose?

Comment: No, the sum must start at $m = 0$. I interpret $\binom{-1}{l} = (-1)^{l}$.

Comment: @user: That is non-"standard", isn't it? Why don't you edit the question with what you mean by $\binom{n}{r}$ when $n \lt r$ (and not just for $n=-1$.)?

Comment: @Moron: Edited.

Comment: [$\binom{-1}{l} = (-1)^{l}$ is actually reasonable.](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Binomial/27/01/0005/)

Comment: @J.M: Hence the "standard" in quotes :-)

Comment: I mean your sum is in terms of $n$ and $l$, but has no $r$...

Comment: @J.M.: Edited for clarity. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\sum_{m=0}^n (-1)^{n-m} \binom{n}{m} \binom{m-1}{l} = (-1)^{l+n} + \sum_{l+1 \leq m \leq n} (-1)^{n-m} \binom{n}{m} \binom{m-1}{l}$$
So we need to compute this last sum. It is clearly zero if $l \geq n$, so we assume $l < n$.

It is equal to $f(1)$ where $f(x)= \sum_{l+1 \leq m \leq n} (-1)^{n-m} \binom{n}{m} \binom{m-1}{l} x^{m-1-l}$.
We have that $$\begin{eqnarray*} f(x) & = & \frac{1}{l!} \frac{d^l}{dx^l} \left( \sum_{l+1 \leq m \leq n} (-1)^{n-m} \binom{n}{m} x^{m-1} \right) \\
& = & \frac{1}{l!} \frac{d^l}{dx^l} \left( \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{x} + \sum_{0 \leq m \leq n} (-1)^{n+1} \binom{n}{m} (-x)^{m-1} \right) \\
& = & \frac{1}{l!} \frac{d^l}{dx^l} \left( \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{x} + \frac{(x-1)^n}{x} \right) \\
& = & \frac{(-1)^{n+1+l}}{x^{l+1}} + \frac{1}{l!} \sum_{k=0}^l \binom{l}{k} n(n-1) \ldots (n-k+1) (x-1)^{n-k} \frac{(-1)^{l-k} (l-k)!}{x^{1+l-k}}
 \end{eqnarray*}$$
(this last transformation thanks to [Leibniz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule#Higher_derivatives))
and since $n>l$, $f(1)=(-1)^{l+n+1}$.

In the end, your sum is equal to $(-1)^{l+n}$ if $l \geq n$, $0$ otherwise.

Comment: choosing some values $l$ and $n$ and summing the series numerically, I seem to get 0 for $l<n$; $(-1)^{l+n}$ I only get for $l\geq n$...

Comment: You are right, I forgot a term. Corrected.

Answer (score 8):

This is a special case of the identity $$\sum_k \binom{l}{m+k} \binom{s+k}{n} (-1)^k = (-1)^{l+m} \binom{s-m}{n-l},$$ which is identity 5.24 on p. 169 of *Concrete Mathematics*, 2nd edition.  With $l = n$, $m = 0$, $s = -1$, $k = m$, and $n = l$, we see that the OP's sum is $$(-1)^{2n} \binom{-1}{l-n} = \binom{-1}{l-n}.$$
This is $(-1)^{l-n}$ when $l \geq n$ and $0$ when $l < n$, as in Fabian's comment to Plop's answer.

Comment: Great stuff! I'm far away from my copy of CM, and Google won't let me peek, so... is there a justification in the book? (If so, I'll look it up myself when I get to my library.)

Comment: I found a copy [here](http://www.google.com/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=concrete+mathematics)

Comment: @J.M.: There is a derivation on p. 170 that uses induction.  They also mention that "we can reduce it to Vandermonde's convolution by a sequence of transformations."

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\sum_{m = 0}^{n}\pars{-1}^{n - m}{n \choose m}{m - 1 \choose \ell}:\
     {\large ?}.\qquad\ell \geq 0}$

> \begin{align}
> &\color{#66f}{\large\sum_{m = 0}^{n}\pars{-1}^{n - m}{n \choose m}
> {m - 1 \choose \ell}}
> \\[3mm]&=\pars{-1}^{n}\sum_{m = 0}^{n}\pars{-1}^{m}{n \choose m}
> \oint_{0\ <\ \verts{z}\ =\ a\ <\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{m - 1} \over z^{\ell + 1}}
> \,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> \\[3mm]&=\pars{-1}^{n}\oint_{0\ <\ \verts{z}\ =\ a\ <\ 1}
> {1 \over z^{\ell + 1}\pars{1 + z}}
> \sum_{m = 0}^{n}{n \choose m}\pars{-z - 1}^{m}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> \\[3mm]&=\pars{-1}^{n}\oint_{0\ <\ \verts{z}\ =\ a\ <\ 1}
> {1 \over z^{\ell + 1}\pars{1 + z}}
> \bracks{1 + \pars{-z - 1}}^{n}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> \\[3mm]&=\oint_{0\ <\ \verts{z}\ =\ a\ <\ 1}{1 \over z^{\ell - n + 1}\pars{1 + z}}
> {\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> =\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{k}\oint_{0\ <\ \verts{z}\ =\ a\ <\ 1}{1 \over z^{\ell - n - k + 1}}{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> \\[3mm]&=\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{k}\,\delta_{\ell - n,k}
> =\color{#66f}{\large\left\lbrace\begin{array}{lcl}
> \pars{-1}^{\ell - n} & \mbox{if} & \ell \geq n
> \\[2mm]
> 0&&\mbox{otherwise}
> \end{array}\right.}
> \end{align}

Comment: I applied your method to a combinatorial sum at this [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/792567/evaluating-combination-sums).